# Migrate from jenkins 1 to jenkins 2

Tags: jenkins

How can we migrate our jenkins 1 instance to jenkins 2.
We know the job export plugin which can be useful for all our the jobs but is there also a way to export your general settings / security settings?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins 2 is a drop-in replacement. You can just upgrade from version 1 to 2, either by updating the server running Jenkins, or by copying the Jenkins directory.

Comment: Problem is that the people above me see this as an opportunity to move everything to a new server (an existing jenkins 2) so we can't just upgrade :/

Comment: So.. figure out where Jenkins stores its data and copy it over? Not sure, what you expect us to tell you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't export anything. Jenkins stores EVERYTHING in 1 directory (unless you have told it not to). Copy that entire directory to a new machine. Copy the existing jar. Start up Jenkins. If it works, replace the jar with the new version. Start it up. Chances are, it will just work.